# none type, don't know how to get rid of it

Tags: python

I'm having a problem with some coding that I'm doing for a school assignment, the same thing happened and I managed to fix it but I did so without knowing how I did it.

```
def number():
    num = input("please enter the number of people that would like play:")
    try:
        if int(num) >= 2:
            if int(num) <=7:
                return num
            else:
                print("number must be 7 or less")
                number()
        else:
            print("number must be greater than 2")
            number()
    except:
        print("that is not a valid number. number must be between 2 and 7")
        number()
number = number()
print(number,"people are playing")
```

This is the code which is causing the problem. If I enter an invalid number it works fine, I can just re-enter a new number, but as you can see I have wanted to print out the "number of people playing" but it returns with "none people are playing" but this is only after I have entered an invalid number. What can I do?

Comment: What do you want it to do when you enter an invalid number?

Comment: `number = number()` is a bad idea, it means you will not be able to use the `number` function after that.

Comment: no i'm trying to make that def a variable so that is can call it later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the ideal case, without any errors, `number()` returns the entered `num` and all is well. However, in all other cases, you end the function with a recursive call to `number()` without actually returning anything. So the function implicitly returns `None` (i.e. nothing).

Just change every recursive call to `return number()` and it should work.

Btw. you should avoid recursion for this; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659/216074) on how to best ask the user repeatedly for valid input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop rather than calling your routine again which will not have the effect you are looking for (look into recursion). Something like the following approach would be better:

```
def number():
    while True:
        num = input("please enter the number of people that would like play: ")

        try:
            num = int(num)

            if num > 7:
                print("number must be 7 or less")
            elif num <= 2:
                print("number must be greater than 2")
            else:
                return num
        except:
            print("that is not a valid number. number must be between 2 and 7")

number = number()
print(number, "people are playing")
```

The reason you are seeing `None` is that it is possible to reach the bottom of your function without a `return` being used. In this case Python defaults the returned value to `None`.